# Revit API Class Opening Infomation

Tags: c#, autodesk, revit, revit-api

can we add new parameters to the opening class in Revit?

not for the shaft opening but for the others opening:

Rectangular Straight Wall Opening
Floor Opening cut
Roof Opening Cut

can we change the opening class family name or add parameter to the opening class element.

very very appreciate if anyone can help me..

Answer (score 0):

Shared Parameters (created by code or by UI) are only available for elements. So as long as you use a Opening element, you can add shared parameter information. But note the shared parameter is valid for all elements of certain kind.

Here is some information from the Revit Help File about **Autodesk.Revit.DB.Opening**

> The object represents a variety of different types of openings:
>
> 1. A rectangular opening in a wall created by two boundary points in a revit project.
> 2. An opening created by a set of curves applied to a roof, floor, ceiling, beam, brace or column.
> 3. A vertical shaft opening extending one or more levels.
> 4. A simple opening created on a wall or ceiling in a family document.
>
> Depending upon the type of opening, some of the properties of this class will not be available.